# why MFC RICHEDIT Control use sendmessage EM_POSFROMCHAR return 0?

Tags: mfc, position, richedit

There is a problem when use `MFC RICHEDITCTRL` in the texteditor project, I use follow code to append string to control, like this:

```
m_editOutputDisasm.SetSel(-1, -1);
m_editOutputDisasm.ReplaceSel(strOutput);
```

Then when I get one char position use `sendmessage(EM_POSFROMCHAR)`，`Return 0`, is error pos. If it ok will return the coordinates of the char.

```
int nDim = SendMessage(EM_POSFROMCHAR, charindex,0);
rect.left = LOWORD(nDim);
rect.top = HIWORD(nDim) + 2;
SetTextColor(pdc->m_hDC, pWdInfo->Color);
DrawText(pdc->m_hDC, pMyBuff, -1, &rect, 0);
```

Questions:

1. richedit contains more data,is the data size greater than richedit's capacity, is the index of char greater than the richedit's capacity that generate this error?
2. `charindex=xxxxx` is `ok,charindex=xxxxx+1` is error?i think richedit has a buffer,size is xxxxx?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use GetCaretPos() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to retrieve the position of the caret

Comment: thanks. i use the other way